# Begin with mutiple inserts giving syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

new to SQL here, and been stuck on this tiny issue that I cannot solve for the love of my life.

What I want to do: Insert into table1, then insert into table2 in the same database query.

I have this SQL statement:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO "questionsGroup" DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO questions (name, category, explanation, "belongsToGroup") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, lastval('questionsGroup'));
END;
```

When running, I get this error:

```
error: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
```

This is how I call the query:

```
const response = await database.insertQuestionsIntoDatabase(query, ["cevin", 1, "test", 8]);
```

And the function:

```
public async insertQuestionsIntoDatabase(sqlStatement: string, values: Array<string | number>): Promise<any> {
        console.log(sqlStatement);
        try {
            return await this.databaseClient.query(sqlStatement, values);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw new Error("Something went wrong with DatabaseQueries Query")
        }
    }
```

What am I missing, most likely something trivial? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to just want to include the `quationsGroup` id into the `qustions` table.  If so, you can use `insert` in a `CTE`:

```
WITH qg AS (
       INSERT INTO questionsGroup
           DEFAULT VALUES
           RETURNING *
      )
INSERT INTO questions (name, category, explanation, belongsToGroup
    SELECT $1, $2, $3, qg.questionsGroupId
    FROM qg;
```

Note it is not considered a good practice to use double quotes for identifiers.  It just makes writing queries that much more complicated.

Comment: Yeah I have seen people use this so called CTE. I have yet looked into it and therefore am not familiar with the syntax, but I do believe that I will look into that. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @CevinThomas So you found the answer useful? Then up-vote it. I sure have.

Comment: What if we have to use double quotes because our table names and table columns are in pascal case, like this: "SalesOrders". What do you suggest for this? Should I convert names to snake case or use double quotes because I know PostgreSQL applies lowering on table and column names.

Comment: @N.Dogac . . . You *can* use double quotes.  Postgres certainly supports it.  I recommend against using it.  Postgres identifiers (following the standard) are case-insensitive, so you can use mixed case -- in fact, all are converted to upper case internally.

Answer (score 0):

Example found in the PostgreSQL **Documentation** for the [`BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-begin.html#id-1.9.3.47.8) statement:

> To begin a transaction block:
>
> ```sql
> BEGIN;
> ```

Notice the `;`.

[`BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-begin.html) and [`END`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-end.html) starts and stops a transaction. They are *not* structural constructs.

Comment: unfortunately, if i do that, then i get this error instead: error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Comment: @CevinThomas So? Execute 2 statements by calling `executeUpdate()` on two different `PreparedStatement` objects (though the first can be a simple `Statement`).